# How to send news feed from facebook canvas app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

Now i am learning how to create Facebook app. I created the canvas app. I send app request to my friend. She can use my app. She send app request to her friends. Now I want to show who are using my app to my other friends. Like Miss.X and Miss.Y using 'this app'. How can i do that. I couldn't find any solution for now.

I am using Rails3 and Ruby1.8